# Code Not Filling Table Cells Individually, Filling Whole Columns Instead

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I have a button that takes the data from a listbox and puts it into specific cells of my table. My problem right now is when inserting the value into the cells it fills the whole column that cell is in instead of the specific cell.

Here is the code for the button:

```
Private Sub cbSubmit_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim vTable() As Variant

 Set inventoryTable = cSheet.ListObjects("inventory_table")
    colItemID = inventoryTable.ListColumns("Item #").Index
    colSpecs = inventoryTable.ListColumns("Specs").Index

    v = inventoryTable.DataBodyRange.Rows
    ReDim vTable(1 To UBound(v, 1), 1 To 4)
    For i = 0 To lbItemList.ListCount - 1

        vTable(i + 1, 1) = "=DATA!" & lbItemList.List(i, 2)

        If specLink = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else

            vTable(i + 1, 4) = lbItemList.List(i, 1)

        End If
    inventoryTable.DataBodyRange(i + 1, colItemID).Value = vTable(i + 1, 1)
    inventoryTable.DataBodyRange(i + 1, colSpecs).Value = vTable(i + 1, 4)
    Next

Unload Me
End Sub
```

This is how it looks after I run the button.
[image: This]

I want it to only fill in the first cell in Item # and then the cell in Specs in that same row. Then go down the rows each cell and fill in the next item. Instead each item gets filled overtop the old items.

Comment: `DataBodyRange` [represents the range of values, excluding the header row, in a table. Read-only.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841252.aspx)

Comment: So data body range will select and edit the whole range and not the specific cell even when it is defined? Is there a way to narrow it down to the cell? I have tried a few ways (used range instead of databodyrange, I tried 'InventoryTable.listcolumns("Item #").databodyrange(i+1, colItemID).value', 'inventoryTable.cells', etc.) and nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting individual cells in a structured table (*aka* [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx)) then you need to turn of the [AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840728.aspx).

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
```

This can also be achieved with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then go to the *AutoFormat As You Type* tab and uncheck *Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns*.

Optionally turn it back on at the end of your sub procedure if you wish to have this application-wide option available.

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
```

Comment: This fixed it thanks so much! I set it so it disables at workbook open and then before close it enables it. I thought my code was right.